# How run a python script every x seconds

Tags: python, multithreading

I have tried the `schedule` library however my code stalls sometimes which also means the schedule code stalls.

```
import schedule
import time
import app

schedule.every(3).seconds.do(app.run)
while 1:
    try:
        schedule.run_pending()
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        pass
```

`app.run` is the script, it using Queues and Threads to request exchange data. One of the exchanges randomly throws an error and because the of threading (I think) the code goes into a state of limbo. I can't seem to fix the bug, but a dirty fix to the problem would be force run the script every x time (in my case I want 10 seconds) Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the obvious way (have a thread that with `while True:` containing `action()` and `sleep(10)`), you can use [threading.Timer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects) or the [sched module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html#module-sched).

Comment: Hi @Raymond Hettinger sorry after considering what you said I can't actually figure out how to write the script. How would would construct the code using threads to solve my problem ?